# Can a Google Cloud Internal Load Balancer be called from other network in same region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

The *Google Cloud Internal Load Balancer* documentation lists the limitation that you need to access it from within the same region. I can't seem to find whether you can access it from within a different network within the same region.

**e.g.** Suppose the *Internal Load Balancer* is in a network 'ilb-network' in europe-west1 (`10.11.x.x`). Can a VM in the 'clients-network' (`10.9.x.x`) access this load balancer (by its `10.11.x.x` IP)?

Answer (score 1):

You can [enable global access](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal#ilb-global-access) to allow client VM instances from any region to access your internal TCP/UDP load balancer.

If the VM is in a different VPC network, in that case you will also need to create a [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) between both network on top of enabling global access. This will allow the VM that is in a different region and different vpc network to connect to the internal LB.